# Function not scanning for second value

Tags: c

I had to write a roshambo function in C for class and am having a small amount of trouble. I am calling the getThrow(int playerNum) function to get a character input from the user, but it only scans for a value the first time it is called. To clarify, when running it will only have the user enter a value for player one and no input can be given for the second call. I tried researching the issue, but couldn't find what is wrong with the code. I can get it to run without using a function to get the input, and instead have the variables be assigned in the main, but I'd really like to know what I am doing wrong to make me a better coder in the long run. The code is as follows(ignore the checkWinner function that works as needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getThrow(int playerNum);
void checkWinner(char p1Throw, char p2Throw);

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char p1Throw = getThrow(1);
    char p2Throw = getThrow(2);

    printf("Player 1's throw: %c\n", p1Throw);
    printf("Player 2's throw: %c\n",p2Throw); 
    checkWinner(p1Throw, p2Throw);

    return 0;
}

char getThrow(int playerNum)
 {
    char throw;
    printf("Player %d, please enter your choice <p>aper, <r>ock, or <s>cissors:\n", playerNum);

    scanf("%c", &throw);

     return throw;
    
   
}

void checkWinner(char p1Throw, char p2Throw) {
   

    if ((p1Throw == 'p') && (p1Throw == 'r'))
        printf("\nPlayer1 wins! Paper covers_rock!");
    else if ((p2Throw == 'p') && (p1Throw == 'r'))
        printf("\nPlayer2 wins! Paper covers_rock!");
    else if ((p1Throw == 'r') && (p2Throw == 's'))
        printf("\nPlayer1 wins! Rock breaks scissors!");
    else if ((p2Throw == 'r') && (p1Throw == 's'))
        printf("\nPlayer2 wins! Rock breaks scissors!");
    else if ((p1Throw == 's') && (p2Throw == 'p'))
        printf("\nPlayer1 wins! Scissors cut paper!");
    else if ((p2Throw == 'p') && (p1Throw == 's'))
        printf("\nPlayer2 wins! Scissors cut paper!");
    else
        printf("\n Draw, nobody Wins");

    return;
}
```

thank you for any and all help!

Comment: `if ((p1Throw == 'p') && (p1Throw == 'r'))`?

Answer (score 0):

when the user enters a char, for the program to see that char, the user must also enter a 'return' ('\n') key.  That 'return' key is not consumed on the first call to `scanf()` so that is what is read in the second call to `scanf()`

To fix the problem, there are several possibilities.

change the call to read two characters:

```
 char dummy;
 scanf( "%c%c", &throw, &dummy );
```

OR add a call to consume the 'return':

```
 scanf( "%c", &throw );
 getchar();
```

Of course, for robust code, should be checking the returned value from the call to `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.

```
 if( scanf( "%c", &throw ) != 1 )
 {
    fprintf( 'stderr', "scanf failed to read the input char\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
 }
 getchar();
```

However, If it were my code, I would write the call to `scanf()` as:

```
scanf(" %c", &throw);  // notice the leading space in the format string.
```

Notice this does not add any extra variables nor any extra function calls and requires minimal change to the OPs code.

Note: the leading space results in any 'white space' being consumed.  On the first call to `scanf()` nothing will change.  On the second call to `scanf()`, the left over '\n' (which is one of the 'white space' characters) will be consumed.

Answer (score -1):

You read only one character. But the user will likely hit at least two characters since you won't start reading until they hit "enter". Since you only read one of those characters, the second read of a character will read the "enter".

My recommendation is this: If you want to read in a line of input and parse it, write code that reads in a line of input and parses it. Don't read a character if you want to read a line.

Comment: the OP says (as does the code) to only read a single char, so this answer is not correct

Comment: @user3629249 Then your answer is incorrect too, since it modifies his code to read more than one character. It's quite obvious that the OP is mistaken in his belief that he wants to read one character. Your proposed suggestion won't read one character either, it will read the newline from the previous input. So if the OP really only wants to read one character, we're both wrong. If he wants to parse a line (as I strongly suspect), my answer is right and yours is wrong.